# How to fix programmatically the search bar in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I programmatically created a search bar in ViewController.
But when I scroll up the screen, the search bar goes up.

How can I freeze the search bar?

```
class searchbarTable:  UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
        self.tableview.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }
}
```

Comment: change `UITableView` style from `plain` to `grouped`

Comment: I changed it and the result is still the same. Keep scrolling up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this and set searchbar in Navigation Bar

```
self.navigationController?.searchDisplayController = searchController
```

OR

```
lazy var searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectZero)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchBar.placeholder = "Search"

    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
}
```

OR

```
var leftNavBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView:Yoursearchbar)
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftNavBarButton
```

OR

```
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

it hide naviationbar when we present okay

Hope it helps You :)

Comment: if this answer is helpful for you then please upvote my answer so other people can find it easily . Thank You